# How can i use the searchBar to search in a tuple?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi friends i want to use the element searchBar to make search in a tuple, i made something similar using just array of string using this: in the delegate of the SearchBar for an array:

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {




   self.ListaDeElementosEncontrados = 



    self.ListaDEElementosTotoales.filter({$0.lowercased() 
    .prefix(searchText.count)==searchText.lowercased()})

    self.searching = true

    self.tableListElementosOfSubc.reloadData() */

   if(self.searchBar.text == ""){
        self.searching = false
       self.tableListElementosOfSubc.reloadData()
    }



}
```

but i want now make a search in a tuple that i have:

this the tuple filled with data :

```
var ListaDEElementosTotoales : [(String,Float)] = []
```

and this is the tuple i think must have all the result data of the search

```
var ListaDeElementosEncontrados : [(String,Float)] = []
```

so how i cant make a search in a tuple?
in that tuple will go Fruits,Price

thank you.

by the way i will use then the tuple:

```
ListaDeElementosEncontrados
```

for fill my tableView thank you.

Comment: Don't use tuples like that.

Comment: so ? :) thank you.

Comment: Exactly, use a struct instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, you can access a tuple's first element using `tuple.0` and the second one using `tuple.1`.

This code should work for you:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var searching = false

    var tableListElementosOfSubc: UITableView!

    var ListaDEElementosTotoales : [(String,Float)] = []

    var ListaDeElementosEncontrados : [(String,Float)] = []

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.ListaDeElementosEncontrados = self.ListaDEElementosTotoales
            .filter {
                $0.0.lowercased()
                    .starts(with: searchText.lowercased())
            }

        self.searching = searchBar.text != ""

        self.tableListElementosOfSubc.reloadData()
    }

}
```

However, I would recommend to use declarations like these:

```swift
    var ListaDEElementosTotoales : [(fruit: String, price: Float)] = []

    var ListaDeElementosEncontrados : [(fruit: String, price: Float)] = []
```

This would make the search code more legible:

```swift
        self.ListaDeElementosEncontrados = self.ListaDEElementosTotoales
            .filter {
                $0.fruit.lowercased()
                    .starts(with: searchText.lowercased())
            }
```

Good luck with your project!